Would Eth Universe freeze funds and give me 7 days to pay 100% of balance as a penalty to get funds released? They suspected i was copy trading
While trading in Eth Universe through Trust wallet, my funds were frozen as they suspected 1 of 3 arbitrage or copy trading. I was directed by support to pay 100% of current balance and if no suspicious activity, all funds would be released for trading. Has anyone seen this before?

Sorry to hear, that sounds like a scam.
